Tic Tac Toe will execute win function randomly
I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game but sometimes it executes the win function for no reason though sometimes, the game doesn't end and no one won yet. Heres the program for your extra information:
from numpy import array

board = array([
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0],
    [0,0,0]
])

turn = 1

def win():
    print(board)
    print('\nYou Win!\n')

while True:
    print(board)

    row = int(input('Row: '))
    column = int(input('Column: '))

    board[row,column] = turn

    if (board[0,0] == turn and board[1,1] == turn and board[2,2] == turn) or (board[0,2] == turn and board[1,1] == turn and board[2,0]): #diagonals
    win()
    break

    if (board[0,0] == turn and board[0,1] == turn and board[0,2] == turn) or (board[1,0] == turn and board[1,1] == turn and board[1,2] == turn) or (board[2,0] == turn and board[2,1] == turn and board[2,2] == turn): #columns
    win()
    break

    if (board[0,0] == turn and board[1,0] == turn and board[2,0] == turn) or (board[0,1] == turn and board[1,1] == turn and board[2,1] == turn) or (board[0,2] == turn and board[1,2] == turn and board[2,2] == turn): #rows
    win()
    break

    if turn == 1:
        turn += 1
    else:
        turn -= 1


Your if statements seem to be saying that, to win, you need to have one of the diagonals and one of the columns, and one of the rows filled in.

One player tic-tac-toe?

Also, you didn't post the traceback error. Or do you have some different code that you haven't posted?

The if statements checking for a win should also be checking if board values == turn instead of checking != 0.  As written, besides the issues quamrana pointed out, it would currently count a row of "X O X" as a win.
Move the code that swaps the value of turn to be after the check for a winner, that way you are checking for the player that just moved.

@SIGHUP It appears to be two player as the board value is set to the value of turn, and turn alternates between 1 and 2, but the current checks for a winner are only checking for the spaces to be filled in, and not to all be the same value.

@nigh_anxiety There is no check on the input values (row & column) to determine if the cells are [already] occupied so it might as well be a solitaire version ;-)

@SighUp - that's true, but at an early testing phase, that can be ignored, with the assumption it would be added later.  it is still switching "players" each turn even it doesn't handle the rest of the checking correctly yet.

You printing Win when all of the win conditions are true, because you nested all the win if cases.
if(..diagonals..):
    if(..columns..): # this works only when the diagonals and columns case is true
        if(..rows..): # this works when diagonals, rows and columns case is true
            print("You win") # this works when all the above cases are true

So, instead checking for all win conditions at once, check one at a time, so if any one of the condition is true the user wins.
if(...diagonals...):
    print("You win")
    break
if(...columns...):
    print("You win")
    break
if(...rows...):
    print("You win")
    break

Reducing the above code with a isWin variable
isWin = True
if(...diagonals...):
    isWin = True
if(...columns...):
    isWin = True
if(...rows...):
    isWin = True

if(isWin):
    print("You Win")
    break;

Hope this helps.
